# If $X$, $Y$ are i.i.d. random variable with $E(X)= 0$ and $Var(X) = 1$ and $(X+Y)/\sqrt{2}$ has the same distribution as $X$, then $X \sim N(0,1)$.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

As stated in the title, I think there already exists answer to the question by using CLT. However, I have come up with another proof which I want some opionion on.

**My attempt**:

Let $\phi(t)$ be the characteristic function of $X$ and $Y$, by the assumption, we have
$$
\phi^2(t/\sqrt{2}) = \phi(t).
$$
Now let $g$ be a function such that
$$
g(t^2) = \phi(t).
$$
We then have for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$,
$$
g^2(t^2/2) = g(t^2).
$$
Furthermore, as $\phi$ is continuous everywhere, this means that $g(t^2)$ is continous on $[0, \infty)$. Now the above implies that $g$ must be an exponential function of $t^2$, and we have
$$
\phi(t) = g(t^2) = e^{ct^2}
$$
for some $c \in \mathbb{R}$. Now plug in the condition that $Var(X) = 1$, we obtain that $c = -1/2$. Therefore,
$$
\phi(t) = e^{-t^2/2}
$$
which is the characteristic function of a standard normal.

Is this proof correct? Thank you!

Comment: Jumping straight to it being an exponential from there seems incomplete. Also, you have already assumed here that $\phi$ is an even function in saying that such a $g$ exists.

Comment: why not though? because I remember if we have a continous function $f$ satisfying $f(ax)f(ax) = f(2ax)$ for some $a$, then $f$ must be an exponential. Or is there still some other condition required?

Comment: @Ian Ok yeah I think assuming the existence of such a $g$ is a little handwavy, but I can construct such a $g$ for the case when $t > 0$ and $t < 0$, and the resulting conclusion is the same?

Comment: What I mean is something like $\phi(t) = g(t^2)$ if $t \geq 0$ and $\phi(t) = g(-t^2)$ for $t < 0$. Does it work in this case?

Comment: On positive $t$ I think there may be a solution to the functional equation involving a periodic function of $\log_{\sqrt 2}(t)$. Perhaps you can eliminate this by continuity at $0$ - I am not sure.

Comment: Once you perform this cleanup and use that functional equation property then you're fine. That functional equation property is the real meat and potatoes of the proof though.

Comment: @Ian $\phi$ is not because it doesn't satisfy the form $f(ax)f(ax) = f(2ax)$ or more generally $f(x)f(y) = f(x+y)$.

Comment: Yeah, I spotted the problem, you get a factor of $\sqrt{2}$ instead of a factor of $2$.

Comment: [another approach](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1034736/if-the-sum-of-two-i-i-d-random-variables-is-normal-must-the-variables-themselv)

Comment: I have looked around and confirmed that the property $f(ax)f(ax) = f(2ax)$ together with the properties of c.f. will imply that $f$ must be expoenetial. BUT, I think there is a pitfall here that might not be addressed. our $g$ here might be a complex function and the above exponential argument is restricted to the reals. If anybody has some pointer on confirming the exponential properties still holds in complex domain then I think this proof should work.

Comment: The $f(x+y)=f(x) f(y)$ functional equation works on the complex numbers but I am less sure about this $f(x+x)=f(x)^2$ case.

Comment: @Ian I think another way of looking at it is to take the $\log$, then you have $h(x) = \log f(x)$ satisfying $2h(x) = h(2x)$ for all $x$. This should imply that $h$ is linear but I am not very familiar with taking $\log$ of complex numbers so I am not sure if this works.

Comment: It's generally best to avoid the logarithm as much as possible in the complex plane.

Comment: @Ian Yeah, that' what I thought..